Google Workspace / Gmail apparently limiting external recipients to 3000 per hosted domain
I work for an organization whose email, documents, and mailing lists ("groups" in Google parlance) live in Google Workspace, in a Business Plus plan. We have about 120 individual users and a couple hundred groups. A handful of those groups are fairly large; one has over 3000 members.
Recently, we came across a very mysterious issue, in which a couple of emails got rejected in separate occasions, with the message:
The domain ourdomain.com has exceeded its quota for the maximum number of external recipients.
We found this extremely confusing (and concerning), as this message implies a limitation on external recipients for the entire domain. We were aware of Gmail's message sending limitations, but we always thought those applied on a per-user basis. After all, if they're domain-wide, then a limit on external recipients wouldn't make sense, especially with a number as low as 3000. One e-mail or two to a large lists and theoretically that limit is hit, rendering Workspace useless for even a mid-sized organization, even without mailing groups involved. Likewise, the Groups-specific limitations don't shed much light on the matter, and the figures therein are quite high.
To our knowledge this happened twice, in the 19th and 26th of June. One of the messages was from a user to a group of 5 people (1 external), while the other was sent to also sent to a small. We believe that the fact that this happened with messages sent to groups was a coincidence.
Our users are well-behaved, and we couldn't find anything in Gmail's statistics/logs that could explain this in practice. The event on the 26th did coincide with a couple mailings going out to some of the larger groups, but that's as much as we can find. Debugging is difficult, as the Gmail stats graphs don't seem to include messages sent to groups, either.
We've scoured the internet high and low on this topic, but nothing has come up about domain-wide limitations. We've also seen that some colleges use Gmail as a backend, leading us to think this 3000-recipient limit can't be domain-wide. Has anyone ever encountered this situation, and if so, do you know how to deal with it? Our support reps (third-party resellers) aren't of much help.

We've also seen that some colleges use Gmail as a backend, leading us to think this 3000-recipient limit can't be domain-wide. Using that logic, if you create 1,000 user accounts, you should be able to email 3,000,000 external recipients per day. Is that your expectation?

The expectation is that the limit isn't literally "users across the entire domain can only exchange e-mail with only e-mail 3000 external recipients" for a 24-hour period. In an org with lots of collaborator/customer exchange, it seems that limit would be exceedingly easy to trigger.
The error message seems to be clear, but the Google support page isn't. The expectation is that there's additional context to this limit.

Some limits apply per-user while others apply to your domain. From the error message you received, and Google sending limits in Google Workspace, Google Workspace limits your organization to sending 3,000 emails to external recipients from your domain name (including aliases) per day.

External recipients per day
Email addresses outside your primary domain, including domain aliases and alternate domains 3,000

According to that article, the limit applies to a rolling 24 hour period.
